# How can I launch a program from a Web Page?

Tags: browser, remote-access

I simply want to OPEN a program in my pc from a web page. For example, I am out and I take my smartphone, I go to the web page and then I click in a button and in my pc (at home, connected to internet) the program starts. How can I do that?

I tried: Open File
but the browsers (Firefox, Internet Explorer) try to download this file and not open.

Comment: This is neither simple nor trivial.  The security implications alone are huge.  What if someone gains access to the website, then they will have some sort of control of your home PC provided you get the tech to work which would be very, very difficult.  Overall this is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers are incapable of running files on a remote machine, purely out of security reasons, because it could obviously do serious harm. This is only doable if you try to run a file on the machine you are using to visit the website with. There are applications available that can open files on or from a remote machine, but they tend to use a TCP or UDP connection to transfer the data, instead of an HTTP connection.

The best way to go about this, is to install a server application on your PC, and then connect to the PC with a client application on your smartphone.

Just search google for `Remote control smartphone pc`, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using a web page. You must use a VNC. There are many open source versions with mobile client apps.

Comment: It *is* possible. It's not just directly possible.

Comment: Of course is possible--you can have a webserver that contacts your remote pc somehow and it launches something through some service installed on the remote pc's machine--but without writing the pieces to glue all that together I think it'd be relatively hard for the OP to find some "out of the box" solution unless OP is using VNC or something similar.